# How to Trim "[" char from a string in Golang

Tags: string, go, trim

Probably a silly thing but got stuck on it for a bit...

Can't trim a `"["` char from a string, things I tried with outputs:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "this[things]I would like to remove"
    t := strings.Trim(s, "[")

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", t)   
}

// output: this[things]I would like to remove
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cZNwX4fsrw)

Also tried all of those, with no success:

```
s := "this [ things]I would like to remove"
t := strings.Trim(s, " [ ")
// output: this [ things]I would like to remove


s := "this [ things]I would like to remove"
t := strings.Trim(s, "[")
// output: this [ things]I would like to remove
```

None worked. What am I missing here?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You are missing reading the doc. [`strings.Trim()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Trim):

> ```
> func Trim(s string, cutset string) string
> ```
>
> Trim returns a slice of the string s with all **leading and trailing** Unicode code points contained in cutset removed.

The `[` character in your input is not in a *leading* nor in a *trailing* position, it is in the *middle*, so `strings.Trim()` – being well behavior – will not remove it.

Try [`strings.Replace()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings/#Replace) instead:

```
s := "this[things]I would like to remove"
t := strings.Replace(s, "[", "", -1)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", t)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1_78sBjk0C)):

```
thisthings]I would like to remove
```

There is also a [`strings.ReplaceAll()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings/#ReplaceAll) added in Go 1.12 (which is basically a "shorthand" for  `Replace(s, old, new, -1)`).

Comment: Somehow I did missed the 'leading and trailing' par, Thanks

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
   package main

   import (
       "fmt"
       "strings"
   )

   func main() {
       s := "this[things]I would like to remove"
       t := strings.Index(s, "[")

       fmt.Printf("%d\n", t)
       fmt.Printf("%s\n", s[0:t])
   }
```

Comment: This returns the string up to the first '[' which doesn't appear to answer the question above. There is also a panic bug when '[' isn't found.